# how to read a single header for @RequestHeader annotation even if the user gives the duplicate headers

Tags: java, spring

How to read a single header for `@RequestHeader` annotation even if the user gives the duplicate headers. If the user gives two header with same key it is been read as comma separated values. I want it to behave like read always first value and ignore other values. 
I want it to behave like read always first value and ignore other values. Spring by default executes request.getHeaders("key") which returns comma separated value if the key present more than once.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a example on how you get it?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to split the value of the key with `yourString.split(";")` and get the first value of the array, if not null though

Comment: Is spring provides any annotaion to restrict the header key needs to be present only once or read the first value ?

Comment: donno if there is a pre-filter support in header request, don't think so anyways,  but you don't need cause you can filter that on your own, @RequestHeader("Some-Header") gives you the access to it as with @RequestParam